# Pandas - create column with aggregate results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset which has a row for each loan, and a borrower can have multiple loans. The 'Property' flag shows if there is any security behind the loan. I am trying to aggregate this flag on a borrower level, so for each borrower, if one of the Property flags is 'Y', I want to add an additional column where it is 'Y' for each of the borrowers.

The short example below shows what the end result should look like. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Borrower': [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6], 
        'Loan' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
       'Property': ["Y","N","Y","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","N"],
       'Result': ['Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','Y','N','N']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Transform on Property after groupby Borrower. Because the ASCII code of 'Y' is bigger than 'N' so if there is any property which is 'Y' for a borrower, max(Property) will give 'Y'.

```
df['Result2'] = df.groupby('Borrower')['Property'].transform(max)

df
Out[202]: 
   Borrower  Loan Property Result Result2
0         1     1        Y      Y       Y
1         2     2        N      Y       Y
2         2     3        Y      Y       Y
3         2     4        Y      Y       Y
4         3     5        N      Y       Y
5         3     6        Y      Y       Y
6         4     7        N      N       N
7         5     8        Y      Y       Y
8         6     9        N      N       N
9         6    10        N      N       N
```